# How to import / export content type?

Tags: 7, nodes, importing-exporting

In Drupal 6 we had content type export import, I cannot find this in Drupal 7.

Any tips please?

Comment: Could this feature really have been axed? Wow, raised it as a feature request : http://drupal.org/node/1277788

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ended up using the [Bundle Copy](http://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy) module.

Comment: This module does not work properly. In D7 I chose few content types to export, then I chose what fields to export and copied all the generated php code to the new site. The module created new content types, but all the custom fields are missing. Furthermore you cannot create those fields again, because it already exist in database, but it is not displayed when modifiying the content type and neither it is in existing fields you could add. Clearing cache does nothing.

Answer (score 14):

You could use [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) to export and import content types in code.

Comment: Thanks , I know Features but it seems it would be an overkill having to create a module to import a feature. Also managing a feature, if there is a change...

Comment: It may seem like overkill but there are quite a few benefits, such as easy duplication between different sites if needed.

With drush and the point and click interface creation and maintenance isn't a huge deal.

Answer (score 2):

This features was part of CCK module, that you can see move into Drupal core. In their [project page](http://drupal.org/project/cck) the maintainers wrote it:

> content_copy : The D7 branch of the Features module supports expoting
>   and importing content types and fields in 'feature' modules. There is
>   currently no UI to manually export and import field definitions.

So like @digital said, you should use [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features).

Answer (score 1):

+1 upvote on the Bundle Copy module by giorgio79 above - a similar module would be: the [data_export_import](https://drupal.org/project/data_export_import) module.

What I like about data_export_import is that it is an all-in-one module (for export AND import of data. Whereas as with other solutions, the import and export stages are done by separate modules, which *could* mean that extra work is needed ensuring compatibility of the export with the import.)